# How to find sum of factors of $2^{2012}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factoring

This question really is confusing me and I was wondering if there was a simple way this could be achieved. 
I've come up with this so far after skimming through a few articles on the net. I assumed this may be correct as the number is already expressed in terms of its prime factors.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{2012} (2^n)$$

Comment: I don't get what exactly you came up with.

Comment: See [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71550.html).

Comment: Geometric series hint hint

Comment: GP${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $2$ is the only prime factor, the sum of the factors of $2^{2012}$ is indeed: $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2012} 2^k = 2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{2012}\quad\quad\color{red}{\checkmark}$$

Next notice that this is a geometric progression, thus use: $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} ar^k = \dfrac{a(r^{n+1}-1)}{(r-1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this manually for $2^1$, $2^2$, $2^3$, and $2^4$, and see if you can see the pattern.

Comment: Down-voters who don't explain themselves don't help this site.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the sum of the factors of $n = \prod_ip_i^{a_i} $ equals $ \prod_i(1+p_i+p_i^2+ \cdots + p_i^{a_i})$.

Comment: Does this really help with the question? There is only a single prime factor (ignoring multiplicity).